# Conventional jquery plugin vs AMD jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, requirejs, js-amd

I still can't get my head around with this AMD jquery plugin.

```
// UMD dance - https://github.com/umdjs/umd
!function(root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else {
        factory(root.jQuery);
    }
}(this, function($) {
    'use strict';

    // Default options
    var defaults = {

    };

    // Constructor, initialise everything you need here
    var Plugin = function(element, options) {
        this.element   = element;
        this.options   = options;
    };

    // Plugin methods and shared properties
    Plugin.prototype = {
        // Reset constructor - http://goo.gl/EcWdiy
        constructor: Plugin,

        someMethod: function(options) {
            return options;
        }
    };

    // Create the jQuery plugin
    $.fn.plugin = function(options) {
        // Do a deep copy of the options - http://goo.gl/gOSSrg
        options = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            // Create a new instance for each element in the matched jQuery set
            // Also save the instance so it can be accessed later to use methods/properties etc
            // e.g. 
            //    var instance = $('.element').data('plugin');
            //    instance.someMethod();
            $this.data('plugin', new Plugin($this, options));
        });
    };

    // Expose defaults and Constructor (allowing overriding of prototype methods for example)
    $.fn.plugin.defaults = defaults;
    $.fn.plugin.Plugin   = Plugin;
});
```

Some tests,

```
console.log($('.some-element').plugin({
        test: 'option1',
        test2: 'option2'
    }));
```

I always get this empty object,

```
Object[]
```

So how can I use this empty object?

And I want to access the method inside the plugin,

```
    var plugin = $('.element').plugin();
    var instance = $('.element').data('plugin',plugin);
    console.log(instance); // an empty object again!
    console.log(instance.someMethod("hello world"));
```

> TypeError: instance.someMethod is not a function
>
> console.log(instance.someMethod("hello world"));

So how should I do to run the method inside the plugin then?

It is so different from the conventional jquery plugin. AMD's is so difficult to understand. Any idea how I can get this AMD works like the conventional!??

**EDIT:**

Finally I got something,

```
    var plugin = $('.element').plugin();
    var instance = $('.element').data('plugin');
    console.log(instance);
    console.log(instance.someMethod("hello world"));
```

result,

```
Object { element={...}, options={...}, constructor=function(), more...}

hello world
```

Why was it so difficult for the those who comment and answer to point this out! Sigh!

Comment: As I pointed out in your other question, you are simply using the `.data()` method incorrectly. Use `var instance = $('.element').data('plugin');`

Comment: Yes sorry for being dumb. I am reading the doc for `.data()` now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var plugin = $('.element').plugin();
    var instance = $('.element').data('plugin');
    console.log(instance);
    console.log(instance.someMethod("hello world"));
```

result,

```
Object { element={...}, options={...}, constructor=function(), more...}

hello world
```

Answer (score 1):

In your test with `.some-element` you would get an empty jQuery object if `.some-element` matches nothing since `$.fn.plugin` returns what `this.each(...)` returns and the `jQuery.each` function returns exactly the same `jQuery` object as what it was called on.

As to how to get the instance, let's go through each step:

```
var plugin = $('.element').plugin();
```

The line above won't create a plugin if `$('.element')` matches nothing. One thing for sure, the value you assign to `plugin` is equal to `$('.element')`.

```
var instance = $('.element').data('plugin',plugin);
```

In context, the line above is equivalent to `var instance = $('.element').data('plugin', $('.element'));` And the return value of `jQuery.data(key, value)` is the jQuery object itself, so that here `instance` will be equal to `$('.element')`.

```
console.log(instance); // an empty object again!
```

That's what you'd get if `$('.element')` matches nothing.

```
console.log(instance.someMethod("hello world"));
```

This is definitely not going to work.

How to access the plugin instance is detailed in a comment in your code:

```
        //    var instance = $('.element').data('plugin');
        //    instance.someMethod();
```

Of course for this to work, `$('.element')` has to match a non-empty set of elements.

AMD is not a factor **at all** in your problems. All of the issues here have to do with how to use jQuery and how to write jQuery plugins.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. `The line above won't create a plugin if $('.element') matches nothing. ` I don't get it - what should it match? Do you mean that I must have an element called `.element` in my html markup? like <div `class="element">something</div>`?

Comment: ``$('.element')`` searches in the page for all DOM nodes which are elements that have ``element`` (yes, without the leading dot) among their class names (the list of names in the ``class`` attribute). It returns a jQuery object which is a set of the elements found. If no elements match, then the set is empty. This is basic jQuery stuff.

Comment: thanks. well, I have the element in my HTML - `<div class="element">something</div>` but it still return `null`.

Comment: Did you test what ``$('.element')`` *itself* returns? I've never seen ``$()`` called with a selector return the value ``null``, ever.

Comment: of course `$('.element')` return an object. But not this `instance.someMethod();` it returns an error - `TypeError: instance.someMethod is not a function`.

Comment: The error message you get indicate that ``instance`` itself is not ``null`` did you inspect its value in a debugger?